# Exception when using a HardMediumSoftScore in a constraint in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to use a `HardMediumSoftScore` in a constraint but I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The constraintWeight (1hard/0medium/0soft) of class (class org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardmediumsoft.HardMediumSoftScore) for constraintPackage (xxx) and constraintName (xxx) must be of the scoreClass (class org.optaplanner.core.api.score.buildin.hardsoft.HardSoftScore).`

I cannot see anything in the documentation as to why I cannot use a medium score, or that I need to do anything different over using a hard or soft score.

I have the same problem using `v8.9.1-FINAL` and `v8.10.0-FINAL`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some part of your planning domain will contain a reference to `HardSoftScore`.  From this exception message, which is coming from constraints, I'm guessing that your planning solution is using `HardSoftScore` and not `HardMediumSoftScore`.

You are free to use either, but you need to consistently use one or the other.